# Adding a navigation bar refresh button with timer in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to add a navigation bar refresh button to update my table view content that coming from JSON and beside that i want my table view keep updating automatically every 5 minutes if the user hasn't pressed the refresh button and changing the button to be an Activity indicator to let the user that is been updating when the table view updating the data

[image: refresh button image]

my refresh button IBAction code :

```
@IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.getCoinData()
    self.coinTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: what is your question, what is your issue?

Comment: I'm trying to add a navigation bar refresh button to update my table view content that coming from JSON and beside that i want my table view keep updating automatically every 5 minutes if the user hasn't pressed the refresh button and changing the button to be an Activity indicator to let the user that is been updating when the table view updating the data

Comment: And what is your problem so far?

Comment: you don't need activity indicator because it is not a better way. Only hit the web service on every minute or second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 4+**

Create **Timer** & on completion of webservice show the reload icon

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer!
    var refreshBarButtonActivityIndicator: UIBarButtonItem!
    var refreshBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barItemSetUp()
    }
    func barItemSetUp() {
        ///SettingReloadButton
        let image = UIImage(named: "refresh-25")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        refreshBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        ///Setting activity Indicator
        let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        refreshBarButtonActivityIndicator = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        toogleIndicator()
    }
   deinit {    
     timer?.invalidate()
   }
    func toogleIndicator() {
        // 5 minutes = 300 seconds //write here 300
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(refreshNow), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func refreshNow() {
        //here i am creating delay for sample purpose
        //here write your webservice code on completion of webservice change bar button item
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshBarButtonActivityIndicator
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.refreshBarButton
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First add the timer which is refresh data every 5 minutes. At timer, you add the web service.

```
var timer = Timer()
func runTimer(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func updateTimer() {
    self.getCoinData()
    self.coinTableView.reloadData()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    runTimer()      
}
```

Comment: how to let the user it's been updating ?

Comment: you must place activity indicator in your web service. Thats the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

To reload your `UITableView` after every 5 minutes, you need to schedule a `Timer` that executes a block of code every 5 minutes, i.e.

```
var timer: Timer?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 300, repeats: true, block: {[weak self] (tt) in
        self?.getCoinData()
        self?.coinTableView.reloadData()
    })
    timer?.fire()
}

deinit
{
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

You can change the time interval according to your requirement. You need to give the time interval in seconds.